# What does an underscore "_" mean in CSS?

Tags: css

I just found the following snippet in a CSS file:

```
position: fixed;
_position: absolute;
```

What does this underline mean in front of the second `position` statement?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is an old *CSS-Hack* for **IE5, 5.5 & 6**.
All browser will display the `position:fixed` while IE5 - 6 use the `_position`, so it display it `absolute`.

But note: This CSS won't validate! And it won't work for **IE5/MAC**

Answer (score 56):

It's one of a number of CSS "hacks" used to target specific versions of Internet Explorer.

```
selector {
    property: value;   /* all browsers */
    property: value\9; /* < IE9 */
    *property: value;  /* < IE8 */
    _property: value;  /* < IE7 */
}
```

Generally speaking you should [avoid CSS hacks in favor of conditional classes on HTML](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to give alternative directives to WinIE browsers, since they don't support certain features of the latest CSS definitions. Other browsers will ignore the whole definition (e.g. _position: relative), while WinIE will treat it as position: relative.

Comment: Note that this was fixed in IE7 so this hack will only be useful for IE6 and below.