# Is this a possible CSS property?

Tags: css

I found this properties in a CSS file from a know blog. I severely questioned its use and if it is allowed to use them, so here is the code.

```
*margin
*padding
```

**Real example:**

```
.offset1 { 
   margin-left: 11.325966850829%; 
   *margin-left: 11.219583872105%
}
```

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/csshacks.html

Comment: [also relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18106476/497418).

Comment: Yep, it really is! Sorry for a possible duplicated question, I really forgot searching for _Asterisk_. We're all days learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hack to deal with Internet Explorer compatibility

See [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)

Answer (score 1):

It is a hack for Internet Explorer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, used to apply different styles to older IE browsers.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml#unrecommended-asterisk_prefix

Answer (score 1):

Tha means that selector is targeting [ie7 and below](http://briancray.com/posts/target-ie6-and-ie7-with-only-1-extra-character-in-your-css/) only